# How to use print(chr(27) + "[2J")? input() function is not working properly when I use this print() function. Thank you

Tags: python, input, terminal, chr

I am making HangMan game in Python. It is almost ready but when I use *print(chr(27) + "[2J")* to clear the console every time while loop runs, it clears but then my **guess = input("Guess a letter")** is not working. And when I comment it out it works perfectly again. I don't understand what the problem is. I searched to find an answer to my problem, but I couldn't. And I would appreciate if somebody explained how this *print(chr(27) + "[2J")* works.  Below is my code:

```
   #columns  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11                                  
gallowList = [                                                   #rows
          [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","|"," "," \n"],   #0
          [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","|"," "," \n"],   #1
          [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","|"," "," \n"],   #2
          [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","|"," "," \n"],   #3
          [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","|"," "," \n"], #4
                                                            ]          

def gallow(listVar):
    print( "    _____   " + "\n" + 
           "   |     |  "          )
   
    for row in listVar:
        for col in row:
             
            print(col, end = "")
        
    print( " ________|_ " + "\n" + 
           "|          |"        )    




word = input("Think of a word: ")
while word.isspace() or len(word) == 0:
    word = input("Think of a valid word: ")
print(chr(27) + "[2J")  # here I should clear the screen after the player
# neters a word

rightGuesses = []
wrongGuesses = []

for letter in word:
    if letter != " ":
        rightGuesses.append("_")
    else:
        rightGuesses.append(" ")
    

while True:
  
    gallow(gallowList)

    print("Word you are guessing:")
    for letter in rightGuesses:
        if letter == " ":
            print(letter, end = "")
        else:
            print(letter +".", end = "")                
    print("\nWrong guesses:", wrongGuesses)
    if list(word) == rightGuesses:
        print("Guessing Player has won!")
        break
    elif len(wrongGuesses) == 9:
        print("Hanging player has won!")
        break
    
    guess = input("Geuss a letter: ")
    
    while guess.isspace() or len(guess) != 1:
        guess = input("Geuss a valid letter: ")
        
    numOccurInWord = word.count(guess) # 2
    numOccurInRightGuesses = rightGuesses.count(guess) #0
    
    # hello    0                      2
    if numOccurInRightGuesses < numOccurInWord:
        for index in range(len(word)): # hello
            if word[index] == guess: # l == l
                if rightGuesses[index] != guess:
                    rightGuesses[index] = guess
                    break
        
    else:
        wrongGuesses.append(guess)
        if len(wrongGuesses) == 1:
            gallowList[0][3] = "O"
        elif len(wrongGuesses) == 2:
            gallowList[1][2] = "/"
        elif len(wrongGuesses) == 3:
            gallowList[1][3] = "|"
        elif len(wrongGuesses) == 4:
            gallowList[1][4] = "\\"
        elif len(wrongGuesses) == 5:
            gallowList[2][3] = "O"
        elif len(wrongGuesses) == 6:
            gallowList[3][2] = "/"
        elif len(wrongGuesses) == 7:
            gallowList[3][4] = "\\"
        elif len(wrongGuesses) == 8:
            gallowList[4][1] = "/"
        elif len(wrongGuesses) == 9:
            gallowList[4][5] = "\\"
            
    # here every time while loop runs, I want to clear the screen and redraw
    # everything
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

Comment: If this is Windows, there were issues long ago with the `<ESC>[2J` sequence (though it may have been fixed). Try `<ESC>[H<ESC>[J` instead. And, just as an aside, I think you can encode the `ESC` inside the string rather than using `chr()`: try `"\x1b[H\x1b[J"`.

Comment: The `while` loop runs because you are in a `while` loop and never told it to stop. You need to get that `while` in a function so you can break out of it and then come back to it.